# Catch SSH exceptions in a UNIX script

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, openssh

I have a background process in my server which updates my ~/.ssh/authorized_keys frequently. If I ssh from my client machine at the very moment it will fail

*$ ssh my_server date
SSH Version: OpenSSH_5.3p1
user@my_server's password*:

and the ssh will mark the script as failed after a number of tries.

I want to break away and add an exception handling piece to sleep 30 seconds whenever this ssh failure occurs.

Something like

```
             *ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' appsrvr01.myserv.com "date" 2> /tmp/error
             if [ $? -ne 0 ]
             then
               echo -e "\n Please wait..\n\n"
               sleep 1s
             else
               echo -e "\n The Environment is ready to use!\n\n"
               exit 0
             fi*
```

Is there any better approach as the above snippet will still prompt for password

Comment: Why does logging in during this update fail? Are you not atomically replacing the file?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could approach this in one shell script by "flock" on a lock file, and then "flock" in the shell script you run above:

In the script that updates your authorized keys:

```
   (flock 200
   # commands here that modify your authorized_keys file
   ) 200>/tmp/authkey_lock
```

And around the script piece you have posted above:

```
   (flock 200
   ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' appsrvr01.myserv.com "date" 2> /tmp/error
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]
   then
     echo -e "\n Please wait..\n\n"
     sleep 1s
   else
     echo -e "\n The Environment is ready to use!\n\n"
     exit 0
   fi
   ) 200>/tmp/authkey_lock
```

Please see "man flock" for for information about flock.

Comment: Thanks but I have no control over the script which updates the keys as its a group level chef script. I am looking more in the terms of exiting gracefully from the ssh consle